# Abrir um diretório

Tags: java, android

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo que quando eu clico em um botão ele exporta todo o meu banco de dados para um arquivo excel, este arquivo fica dentro de um pasta criada pelo proprio aplicativo, está pasta criada fica na memória interna do aparelho.
A minha pergunta é,  se eu colocar um botão eu consigo abrir está pasta para eu visualizar os arquivos?

Eu tentei algo assim para tentar abrir a pasta que contém os arquivos, mas não obtive sucesso.

```
Uri selectedUri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + 
                  "/DSS_DIGITAL/");
Intent dss_digital = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
dss_digital.setDataAndType(selectedUri, "resource/folder");
startActivity(dss_digital);
```

Agradeço a quem puder ajudar.

Comment: O que acontece é que para visualizar os arquivos do dispositivo, você precisa de um gerenciador de arquivo. Nem sempre os smartphones vem com gerenciador de arquivos, no qual na maioria das vezes, cada pessoa baixa seu preferido, como o [ASTRO](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.metago.astro&hl=pt_BR) ou o [ES File Explorer File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=pt_BR), e outros. Talvez o que da pra fazer, é tentar verificar se alguns deles é possível passar parâmetros para que sugira ao usuário a instalação de um gerenciador.

Comment: Entendi, mais teria como eu sugerir um app tipo, passar o pacote dele ai se este app exigir abrir e se não o app solicitar a instalação?

Comment: Caso seja possível o amigo poderia me mostrar algum código para eu ver como funciona. Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 3):

Para acessar os arquivos do seu dispositivo, é necessário um gerenciador de arquivos. Nem todos os smartphones vêm com um instalado e, portanto, muitas pessoas preferem baixar um aplicativo de sua escolha, como o **ASTRO** ou o **ES File Explorer File Manager**, entre outros.

Um exemplo básico usando o ES File Explorer File Manager (já instalado no dispositivo) seria usando o pacote `com.estrongs.android.pop` e o método `setPackage` para abri-lo. Em seguida, você pode passar o endereço do arquivo usando o `putExtra` da seguinte maneira: `Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath))`. Veja abaixo como ficaria:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.setPackage("com.estrongs.android.pop");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath)));

startActivity(shareIntent);
```

**Obs.:** caso o aplicativo de gerenciamento não esteja instalado, basta fazer uma verificação antes, para que usuário possa instala-lo. Veja aqui [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18752247/2570426) com algumas dicas.

Se você não sabe o nome do pacote do app de gerenciamento de arquivos, uma forma é busca-lo no Google Play e observar a URL. Veja:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: mais tem como eu apontar direto para o meu diretório?

Comment: tipo: com.estrongs.android.pop/SDCARD/MEU_DIRETORIO